# Replace alt attriute using preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove alt attribute using preg_replace. Here is the pattern of alt attribute

```
alt="Screen Shot 2015-06-09 at 11.37.40 AM"
```

or it might be like this

```
alt="The Postmates sign outside the office"
```

There can be any character inside the quotes. I was using following expression:

```
$html = preg_replace('/alt="\w+\s\w+"/', '><br>', $html);
```

but it replaces only alt attributes of type:

```
alt="The Postmates"
```

What would be the appropriate expression here?

Comment: You might get closer with `'/alt="([\w\s]*)"/'`. You would still have a problem with dashes and other special characters, of course. The main point is to use [character sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*?` should do it.

```
$html = preg_replace('/alt=".*?"/', '<br>', $html);
```

This will replace everything in `alt` attribute and its contents with a `<br>`.

Sidenote a `<br>` in an `img` element doesn't make much sense if that's what you are doing... or since you had `><br>` maybe you're trying to close the `img`? Is `alt` always the last attribute?

The `.*?` says find anything until the first "this character", in this case a double quote.... In More detail...

`.` = any character

`*` = 0 or more occurrences of the preceding character (replace with `+` if you want atleast one occurrence)

`?` = makes the `*` lazy, meaning stop at the first occurrence, not the last

A place to test regexs. http://regex101.com, http://www.phpliveregex.com/

A place to learn regexs, http://www.rexegg.com/, http://www.regular-expressions.info/, and many other sites.

Here's a test you can see this regex work with http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/bvn.

Per your update:

```
$html = preg_replace('/alt=".*?"\s*/\?s*>/', '><br>', $html);
```

The `/\` is to escape the forward slash because forward slashes are your delimiter. The `?` after the forward slash is because it is optional. The `\s*` is zero or more whitespace. Those could be on either side of the optional closing forward slash which is why we have both.

Comment: I forgot to put the closing tag. Thanks for the answer. Yes, alt is always the last attribute. Could you please provide me a link to any book or tutorial where I can learn more about regex?

Comment: Links provided as well as updated regex. You also might want to look into HTML/XML parsers.

Comment: Any other questions or issues with this?

Comment: No other question.Your explanation was pretty good. I also loved the website rexegg :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how regexp in PHP differs, but try this one:

```
$html = preg_replace('~alt\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"~', '><br>', $html);
```

In the beginning we have **alt** which is a plain text.
Then **\s*** means "zero or more spaces". It is done to work on code like `alt = "something"`.
**=** stands for a plain equals sign.
**\s*** again.
**([^"]*)** means "any symbol except for quotes.

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation so that I write these expressions myself in future?

Comment: You need delimiters for a regex in PHP. `'alt\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"'` should be `'~alt\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"~'`. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: @chris85 Oh thanks. I just have never worked with regex in PHP :)